# Почему цикл берёт лишние знаки?

Tags: php

Я решаю задачу на поиск самого длинного палиндрома в строке с помощью php.
Код по ссылке:
https://github.com/konorlevich/palindrom/blob/master/palindrom.php

Циклом сравниваются знаки слева и справа от целевого.

Но в некоторых местах цикл ошибочно забирает неодинаковые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему?

Comment: Код целиком с комментариями занимает ~100 строк, поэтому я его не стал писать в вопрос, но оставил ссылку на него

Comment: Так может быть это должно было послужить для вас толчком в сторону локализации проблемы? ;) А уже после этого можно добавить в вопрос _проблемный_ кусок кода.

Answer (score 1):

Подчистил код немного.

Манипуляции в начале не стал убирать.

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru");
$str="ffffsdfefwА роза упала на лапу Азораerysfdh";

$encoding=mb_detect_encoding($str);
$text=mb_strtolower($str, $encoding);
$text=str_ireplace ( " ", "", $text);
$text=str_replace ( ".", "", $text);
$text_arr = preg_split('//u',$text,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$str_len=count($text_arr);
$palindroms = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $str_len; $i++) {
    $_i = $i - 1;
    $i_ = $i + 1;
    $fh = true;


    while ($_i >= 0 && $i_< $str_len) {
        if ($fh && $text_arr[$i] == $text_arr[$i_]) {
            $str = implode(
                '',
                array_slice($text_arr, $i, ($i_ - $i + 1))
            );

            $palindroms[$str] = mb_strlen($str);
            $i_++;
        }

        $fh = false;

        if ($text_arr[$_i] == $text_arr[$i_]) {
            $str = implode(
                '',
                array_slice($text_arr, $_i, ($i_ - $_i + 1))
            );

            $palindroms[$str] = mb_strlen($str); 
        } else {
            continue 2;
        }

        $i_++;
        $_i--;
    }
}

var_dump(
    // All
    array_keys($palindroms),
    // Longest
    array_keys($palindroms, max($palindroms))
);
```

Реализация алгоритма сильно запутанно но похоже что

https://github.com/konorlevich/palindrom/blob/master/palindrom.php#L67 мы символ двигаем и потом сравниваем его с центром а нужно сравнивать с другим крайним!

Как починить код не уверен проще переписат. 
Ну и мой var_dump в придачу.

case 1:
var_dump($i, $*i, $i* ,$text_arr[$i],$text_arr[$_i],$text_arr[$i_], '----');

case 2:
var_dump($i, $*i, $i*,$text_arr[$i],$text_arr[$_i],$text_arr[$i_], '++++');

last if:
var_dump('=============');

```
int(1)
int(0)
int(2)
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(4) "----"
string(13) "============="
int(2)
int(1)
int(3)
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(4) "----"
int(2)
int(0)
int(3)
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(4) "----"
int(2)
int(0)
int(3)
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(4) "++++"
Подпалиндром ffff
string(13) "============="
int(3)
int(2)
int(4)
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(1) "s"
string(4) "----"
int(3)
int(1)
int(4)
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(1) "s"
string(4) "----"
int(3)
int(1)
int(4)
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(1) "s"
string(4) "++++"
Подпалиндром fffs
int(3)
int(0)
int(5)
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
 string(1) "d"
string(4) "----"
int(3)
int(0)
int(5)
string(1) "f"
string(1) "f"
string(1) "d"
string(4) "++++"
Подпалиндром ffffsd
string(13) "============="
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, ваш код работает. Но я не до конца понял, что было не так с моим. Если не сложно, подскажите.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.